# Pi fails apt-get upgrade

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-jessie

My Raspberry Pi 2 running Jessie 8 is failing apt-get upgrade. I also tried removing a package and got the same error. Here is the error 
`addgroup: The group "input" already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'firewall' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and firewall if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service firewall at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping firewall depends on monit and therefore on system facility "$all" which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
the " are actually ' but due to how the forum handles the code insert I had to change it. Any idea how to fix this error.

Updated log: 
`Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up udev (215-17+deb8u5) ...
+ update_hwdb
+ udevadm hwdb --update --usr
+ addgroup --system input
addgroup: The group "input" already exists as a system group. Exiting.
+ [ -z 215-17+deb8u4 ]
+ upgrade_fixes configure 215-17+deb8u4
+ chrooted
+ stat -c %d/%i /
+ stat -Lc %d/%i /proc/1/root
+ [ 45830/2 = 45830/2 ]
+ return 1
+ [ -d /dev/.udev/ -a ! -d /run/udev/ ]
+ dpkg --compare-versions 215-17+deb8u4 lt 171-3
+ dpkg --compare-versions 215-17+deb8u4 lt 204-1
+ chrooted
+ stat -c %d/%i /
+ stat -Lc %d/%i /proc/1/root
+ [ 45830/2 = 45830/2 ]
+ return 1
+ [ -e /etc/udev/kernel-upgrade ]
+ can_start_udevd
+ supported_kernel
+ uname -r
+ return 0
+ [ ! -d /sys/class/ ]
+ ps --no-headers --format args ax
+ egrep -q ^\[
+ grep -q [[:space:]]devtmpfs$ /proc/filesystems
+ [ -e /etc/udev/disabled ]
+ return 0
+ handle_service_rename
+ dpkg --compare-versions  lt 204-1
+ [ -d /run/systemd/system ]
+ systemctl stop udev.service udev-control.socket udev-kernel.socket
+ true
+ rm -f /run/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service
+ rm -f /run/systemd/system/udev.service
+ [ -d /run/systemd/system ]
+ systemctl daemon-reload
+ invoke-rc.d udev restart
+ update_initramfs
+ [ -x /usr/sbin/update-initramfs -a -e /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf ]
+ update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
+ [ -x /etc/init.d/udev ]
+ update-rc.d udev defaults
insserv: warning: script "firewall" missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service monit and firewall if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service firewall at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service monit at depth 1
insserv: Stopping firewall depends on monit and therefore on system facility "$all" which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
+ exit 1
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.120+deb8u2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Most of it looks just to be an echo of something

Comment: When I remove the input group I get http://pastebin.com/9Egp0Svh I had to use pastebin as it was too long for the comment

Comment: Instead of pastebin or a comment you should edit your question and include it there.

Comment: I figured the pastebin would be fine but can you help me figure out how to fix this error

Comment: Pastebin has a few problems: 1) it makes it harder for those who can help - they need to follow the link instead of having all of the pertinent data here. 2) what happens when the link disappears? It then becomes useless for anyone else who may be facing the same problem.

Comment: The system created the input group - so deleting it probably did more harm. Did you install monit or a firewall? You may be better of because of the deleted group just starting over (reinstall Raspbian).

Comment: I installed ufw firewall but is there any way to fix this other than reinstall Rasbian?

Comment: You still have not done as requested and included the pastebin content, but are pushing for an answer. By deleting the group you have made me wonder what else you may have changed - that could be just waiting to cause further issues. If it were me I would restart from scratch and setup  a system of backups.

Comment: I fear that I that is what I will have to do but I will edit the post to include the latest log

Comment: I went ahead and reinstalled Rasbian I am still currently installing it so hopefully this fixes the issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just reinstalling the OS so if you ever get this error just backup what you can and reinstall OS